# Converting PNG to "data:image/png;charset=utf"

Tags: html, artificial-intelligence, png

I am trying to put an image into a deep learning model. When I looked at the Data and how it has to be formatted to fit into the model I found this.

```
 Document: a46c86372d23521d6972748dabdc2fa0
╭───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ Attribute │ Value                                                            │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ adjacency │ 1                                                                │
│ mime_type │ image/png                                                        │
│ text      │ brown cat with flowers, digital art,                             │
│ uri       │ `data:image/png;charset=utf-8,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR`|
│ tags      │ {'text': 'brown cat with flowers, digital art, '}                |
```

So I want to reformat my own png into this

```
data:image/png;charset=utf
```

format (I think it’s HTML5)
I would like to know how I could do this.(turning my png into this format)(websites or programs)
The AI model is called dalle.

Comment: The given image format appears to be an URL-encoded raw PNG image (*not* base64-encoded, but for some reason apparently UTF-8 encoded?)

Comment: Firefox displays it but get's very laggy

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [convert_blob_to_datauri()](https://docarray.jina.ai/api/docarray.document.mixins.blob/)

```
image = Image.open('cat_image.png')
buffered = BytesIO()
image.save(buffered, format='PNG')
doc = Document(
    blob=buffered.getvalue(),
    mime_type='image/png',
    tags={
        'text': 'brown cat with flowers, digital art, '
    },
).convert_blob_to_datauri()
doc.text = 'brown cat with flowers, digital art, '
display(doc)
```

[display(doc) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPBzh.png)